# Help me identify a japanese font

Tags: fonts, font-identification, video, japanese

Can someone please help me identify this japanese font? Need it for a little project I'm doing. Thank you in advance[image]

Comment: Try en.likefont.com to identify it

Comment: We've had a lot of questions on Japanese fonts recently. Unfortunately, it's normally the same answer: nobody here seems to know much about them and these questions rarely get good answers. Try Billy Kerr's suggestion.